# Why can't I use CDATA in email template body in Odoo 11?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11

I was trying to create a new email template for invoices. What I did is to copy all the existing email template for invoices (xml id: `email_template_edi_invoice`) except for the `body_html` field. And here is the problem:

If I fill in the `body_html` using `CDATA`, I get the following asertion error:

```
Element odoo has extra content: data, line 6
```

However, if I do not use it, it works. I simplified the `body_html` content, but the problem is still there.

**The following email template works:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<odoo>

    <data>
        <!--Email template -->
        <record id="email_template_edi_invoice_v8" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Invoicing: Invoice email v8.0</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email and '&quot;%s&quot; &lt;%s&gt;' % (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name} Invoice (Ref ${object.number or 'n/a'})</field>
            <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_invoice"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="report_template" ref="account.account_invoices"/>
            <field name="report_name">Invoice_${(object.number or '').replace('/','_')}_${object.state == 'draft' and 'draft' or ''}</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
<div>
Hola
</div></field>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

**The following email template does not work (gives the extra content error):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<odoo>

    <data>
        <!--Email template -->
        <record id="email_template_edi_invoice_v8" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Invoicing: Invoice email v8.0</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email and '&quot;%s&quot; &lt;%s&gt;' % (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name} Invoice (Ref ${object.number or 'n/a'})</field>
            <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_id.id}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_invoice"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="report_template" ref="account.account_invoices"/>
            <field name="report_name">Invoice_${(object.number or '').replace('/','_')}_${object.state == 'draft' and 'draft' or ''}</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="html"><![CDATA[
<div>
Hola
</div>]]></field>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

Can anyone who experienced this problem give me a hint of what is happening?

Comment: If you remove your `<data></data>` tags, you might get a more useful error. The `data` elements are no longer necessary unless you're wanting to use `noupdate="1"`.

Comment: @travisw I removed `data` tags but then the error message is *Element odoo has extra content: record, line 8*.

Comment: Try using hard-coded values for everything to start? If it loads that, then slowly re-add the `${...}` pieces until it breaks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks otherwise valid but the attribute `type=”html”` could cause your error. Try without it like this

```
  ...
  <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
  ...
```

Comment: That was the problem. Without `type="html"` works. Thank you @Veikko.